# Merge specific column into dataframe

Tags: python, join, merge, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames with the same indices. I would like one column of DataFrame 'B' to be merged into DataFrame 'A'. Standard `pd.merge(A, B)` does not seem to do what I want as it merges all columns from B into A. `pd.merge(A, B['my column'])` doesn't work either as it complains that the 2nd argument is a Series which doesn't have indices.

Another way I could think of was `A['my column'] = B['my column']`, but it also doesn't work because this code gets executed multiple times which always overwrites columns that were already assigned in `A`.

Any help is appreciated.

### Update (example)

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.arange(5)}, index=np.arange(5))
B = pd.DataFrame({'b': ['b', 'b'], 'c': np.random.randint(10, size=2)}, index=np.arange(2))
C = pd.DataFrame({'b': ['c', 'c'], 'c': np.random.randint(10, size=2)}, index=np.arange(2, 4))
print A
print B
print C
A = pd.merge(A, B[['b']], left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
print A
 
A = pd.merge(A, C[['b']], left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
# there should be only one column 'b' in A, not 'b_x' and 'b_y'
print A
```

Output:

```
   a
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4

[5 rows x 1 columns]
   b  c
0  b  0
1  b  2

[2 rows x 2 columns]
   b  c
2  c  2
3  c  3

[2 rows x 2 columns]
   a    b
0  0    b
1  1    b
2  2  NaN
3  3  NaN
4  4  NaN

[5 rows x 2 columns]
   a  b_x  b_y
0  0    b  NaN
1  1    b  NaN
2  2  NaN    c
3  3  NaN    c
4  4  NaN  NaN

[5 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guessing at what you're after, maybe `combine_first` would work?

```
>>> A.combine_first(B[["b"]]).combine_first(C[["b"]])
   a    b
0  0    b
1  1    b
2  2    c
3  3    c
4  4  NaN

[5 rows x 2 columns]
```